# How can I wrap this structure in Python 3 classes?

Tags: python, object, data-structures, python-3.x

I have a structure in my code that is a mix of arrays and dicts that looks like this:

```
items=[{'key1': 'text',#start item1
        'key2': ['text', 'more text'],
        'key3': ['text', 'potentially more text'],
        'key4': 'text',
        'key5': 'text',
        'collection': [{'IDs': [0x01, 0x02],# binary data
                        'objects': [{'subkey1': 0xc3c3c3,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x00,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x90,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x29},# binary data
                                   {'subkey2': 0x53,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x20},# binary data
                                   {'subkey3': 0x56,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x27}]},# binary data
                       {'IDs': [0x01],# binary data
                        'objects': [{'subkey1': 0x90909090, # binary data
                                    'property': 0x00, # binary data
                                    'property': 0x90,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x29},# binary data
                                   {'subkey2': 0x53,# binary data
                                    'property': 0x20}]}]},
       {'key1': 'text',#start item 2
         ... }]# more items here
```

Now, I would love to create an object structure that could contain the above data in several types of objects (for instance an `item` class, a `collection` class, and an `object` class, based on the names above). This would allow me to do conversions on the binary data in the structure easily, for example.

However, I'm struggling to find a structure that matches the above in a good way, and at the same time is extensible (so that I can use inheritance to add to the structure).

My question is (and it may be a dumb one) - how would you represent the above structure as objects/classes in Python 3 code?

Comment: Your question right now is too vague.  What do you need these classes to do?  What do you want to do with your existing structure that you can't do (or can only do awkwardly)?

Comment: Quick and dirty answer: create a class (don't name it `object`) to represent your `'objects'`, then create a class (don't name it `'collection'`) to represent your `'collection'` and give it a member that is a list of the classes representing your `'objects'`, then create an `item` class and give it a member that is the class representing your `'collection'`. Unfortunately your code above is syntactically invalid because you repeat the key `'property'` in your dictionaries...

Comment: Have you looked into struct?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is more specific names.  I'll keep the outside `list` name of `items`, but the dictionaries I'm going to call a `cringe`, `collection` will be renamed to `sharps` which will be a `list` of `Poke`s, and each `Poke` will have a `list` of `IDs` and some `property_nn`s.

```
class Cringe:
    """
    Contains several `keynn` attributes; `Sharps` is a list of `Pokes`
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.sharps = []
    def keys(self):
        """
        Return an iterator of `key...` attributes
        """
        return (k for k in self.__dict__.keys() if k.startswith('key'))

class Poke:
    """
    Contains a list of ids, and possibly several Mulahs
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.IDs = []
        self.mulahs = []

class Mulah:
    """
    Contains one subkey, and possibly several properties
    """
    def __init__(self, subkey, *properties):
        self.subkey = subkey
        for i, prop in enumerate(properties):
            name = 'property_%02d' % i
            setattr(self, name, prop)
    def properties(self):
        """
        Return an iterator of `property_nn` attributes
        """
        return (p for p in self.__dict__.keys() if p.startswith('property_'))
```

Remember: names are important!  :)